# Deploy Vapor Project on macOS Server

Tags: mac-osx, supervisord

I'm trying to deploy a vapor project on a Mac used as a server.
For that, following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ahmedraad/how-to-deploy-vapor-app-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-run-it-in-production-eef18f7b4f05) which I already did before, but on a Linux machine (which worked fine).

I got to the point where I have to set up the supervisor.
Specifically, `supervisorctl start my-app` doesn't work for me:

> my-app: ERROR (spawn error)

In the error logs, I found this:

> Fatal error: Error raised at top level: ⚠️ CommandError: Too many arguments or unsupported options were supplied: ["--"]
>   - id: CommandError.excessInput

This is the `my-app.conf` file:

```
[program:my-app]
command=/usr/local/var/www/my-app/.build/release/Run serve --env production
directory=/usr/local/var/www/my-app
user=linus
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)-stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)-stderr.log

[supervisord]
```

I tried to remove the flags from the command inside the `my-app.conf` file, and then run `supervisorctl reread` but the error persists with the exact same messages...

Any idea what I need to do?

---

Edit: I've tested it on a Ubuntu machine and experienced the same issue. The vapor app builds & runs fine, but the supervisor can't start the program...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure that this was the only thing that solved my issue, but after doing the following, it started working:

1. in the conf file, change the user to `root`
2. run `sudo supervisorctl reload`
3. run `sudo supervisorctl reread`
4. run `sudo supervisorctl start my-app`
5. then check if it's running: `sudo supervisorctl status`

Now, it showed me `RUNNING` for `my-app`.

Maybe this will help anyone coming across the same issue...